# A timer that is pausable in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I go about creating a timer that I could pause using NodeJS?

I was thinking of using setInterval/setTimeout but was unsure if it will work as I want it to? (since there's no "pause")

Basically I want an re-occuring timer every 5 minutes (for example) but if I do a certain action, I want it to pause, and then on another action, unpause.

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but you might want to look at underscore.js functions (http://underscorejs.org/#debounce, http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) which have used timers in interesting ways.

Comment: can you write your answer in pseudocode?

Answer (score 1):

You don't pause a timer in node.js.  Instead, you start and stop a timer.

If you want to start it again with the same amount of time remaining that it would have had left if it kept running, then you just have to keep track of that amount of time.

Here's an idea for a little object that lets you start and stop a timer:

```
var Timer = function(t, fn, go) {
    var timer, tRemaining, tStarted;

    if (!t || !fn) {
        throw new Error("Must specify time and callback function");
    }

    tRemaining = t;

    if (go) {
        this.start();
    }

    this.start = function() {
        if (!timer) {
            tStarted = new Date().getTime();
            timer = setTimeout(fn, tRemaining);
        }
    };

    this.pause = function() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            tRemaining -= now - tStarted;
        }
    }
}

// usage
var t = new Timer(5000, function() {
    // this will be called when the timer is done
});

t.start();

// some time later
t.pause();

// some time later
t.start();
```

Comment: I can't think of a proper way to do this. I mean, should I have a variable with the seconds from the beginning, and have a interval every second that adds/decreases it?

Comment: @MathiasSjöberg - I'll show you some code in a bit.

Comment: Alright, cool. I gonna try something I just thought of, as I don't want you guys to feel like I'm just awaiting to have the code handed to me. :)

Comment: @MathiasSjöberg - code example added.  You can see in the example, that I'm using `setTimeout()` to start the timer, `clearTimeout()` to stop the timer and when it is stopped, I record how much time has already elapsed and subtract that from the original amount of time remaining.  The code ignores calls to `.start()` or `.pause()` if the timer is already started or already paused.

Comment: Many thanks to you. :) While I was waiting, I did something like, added a one second loop, adding +1 each time, and then checking if the variable was going over X minutes (converted seconds into minutes before) then it won't run the function, etc. Is that a bad way to do it?

Comment: @MathiasSjöberg - I can't really tell what code you're asking about.  You'd have to put that actual code in a question for us to look at.  In general it's not a best practice to check something every certain amount of time (that's often called polling) because it does a lot of unnecessary work.  It's better to set a timer for the time you want something to occur and then let the system go to sleep until then (saving battery, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

I long time ago in a [gist far far away](https://gist.github.com/aaditmshah/2056987) I created a constructor for [delta timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing). The constructor called `DeltaTimer` can be started, stopped (paused) and restarted (resumed) whenever required.

Here's how it can be used:

```js
var output = $("output"), start;

var timer = new DeltaTimer(function (now) {
    output.innerHTML = (now - start) / 1000;
}, 1000);

$("start").addEventListener("click", function () {
    start = timer.start();
});

$("stop").addEventListener("click", timer.stop);

function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<span id="output"></span>

<script>
function DeltaTimer(render, interval) {
    var timeout;
    var lastTime;
 
    this.start = start;
    this.stop = stop;
 
    function start() {
        timeout = setTimeout(loop, 0);
        lastTime = Date.now();
        return lastTime;
    }
 
    function stop() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        return lastTime;
    }
 
    function loop() {
        var thisTime = Date.now();
        var deltaTime = thisTime - lastTime;
        var delay = Math.max(interval - deltaTime, 0);
        timeout = setTimeout(loop, delay);
        lastTime = thisTime + delay;
        render(thisTime);
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see the timer corrects itself with a very small margin of error. In addition, it can be easily stopped and restarted.

Hope that helps.